# XML action:wiring

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I've created an simple app with the "SAP Web IDE Full-Stack Storyboard" with a simple Link-Element and a navigation to another view. Afterwards I took a look into the generated code and saw the folloging code:

```xml
<Link
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:action="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
  id="link0"
  text="Navigate to Page2"
  press="action"
  action:wiring="\{'press':\{'navigation':\{'routeName':'Page2'\}\}\}"
/>
```

**Is there any documantation or usage samples for this schema?**

Comment: some here: https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/91/f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/frameset.htm. Search for the schema name and you'll find more.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation about the CustomData Namespace.